# Let $\sigma,\tau$ be stopping times. $\{\sigma<\tau\}\in\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

Consider a filtered prob space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_s)_{s\in [0,T]},\mathbb{P})$ satisfying the usual conditions.
Let $\sigma,\tau$ be stopping times. Is it possible to show that
$$\{\sigma<\tau\}\in\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}?$$
I tried the following:
$$\{\sigma<\tau\}=\bigcup_{q\in[0,T]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{\sigma<q\}\cap\{q<\tau\}$$
Now, fix $s\in[0,T]$. Consider $$A_s:=\{\sigma<q\}\cap\{q<\tau\}\cap\{\sigma\leq s\}$$
and try to show that $A_s\in\mathcal{F}_s$. Then the claim follows by the definition of $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$.
If $q\leq s$, then
$$A_s=\{\sigma<q\}\cap\{q<\tau\}\in\mathcal{F}_q\subset\mathcal{F}_s.$$
If $q>s$, then
$$A_s=\{\sigma\leq s\}\cap\{\tau>q\}$$
and i got stuck.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067567/inequality-between-stopping-times-in-continuous-time